# C - Can You Achieve Pointer Functionality Without Pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, memory-address

I'm basically curious if you could do something like this, without the use of pointers:

```
int myVariable = 0;

int varPointer = &myVariable;

*varPointer += 1; //This obviously won't work, but explains the concept
```

Yes, I know you can do this with pointers. I want to know if it can be done *without* pointers.

EDIT>

I want to be able to refer to an address contained in a variable without pointers.

The question is basically, "Can you achieve pointer functionality without using actual pointers? If so, how?"

Comment: What is your question? Whether you can alter a reference? The answer in no to that.

Comment: Do you mean varPointer+=1 or *varPointer+=1?

Comment: eckes, I basically mean *varPointer +=1. But I don't think you can do that unless it was defined as a pointer. Unless you can? Using the asterisk operator on a variable would be the answer I am looking for, if that is possible.

Comment: If you don't like pointers, don't use C. Try Fortran or any number of other languages that don't have pointers.

Comment: I know how to use pointers and I like them. What I don't like is a still don't really understand how they work. Shouldn't I be able to just tell the compiler to grab a memory address from a variable, goto that address and make the changes there?

Comment: Basically, I get how the `*` operator works, but I don't know why you can't just use the `*` operator on a variable. Why do you /need/ pointers?

Comment: Two main reasons. Type safety and pointer arithmetic. On the second point, what you have shown, `*varPointer+=1` is not pointer arithmetic. It changes the memory contents and not the pointer address. So if there were no pointers how would you achieve pointer arithmetic? You would need to manually get the size of the var type and increment by that many number of bytes.

Comment: Alan, you are right about pointer arithmetic, but they could have easily built in a library function to handle that. As it stands, pointers are confusing and can result in undefined behavior. Which is probably why C++ created the reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses integer arithmetic instead of pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int myVariable = 0;
    uintptr_t varPointer = (uintptr_t)&myVariable;

    varPointer += sizeof myVariable;

    return 0;
}
```

You say in comments:

> pointers /can/ contain addresses, but do not necessarily.

Pointer variables must either be null pointers or contain the address of an object.  If your code appears to do otherwise then your program has already caused undefined behaviour.

"Hex" has nothing to do with it; base 16 is a way of outputting numbers and you can use any base you like.

Bear in mind that pointers do not necessarily correspond to numbers. On platforms where they don't, then `uintptr_t` will not exist.

Comment: What sort of 'platforms' do not correlate pointers to numbers, and on such platforms, what do they point to instead? Why?

Comment: MS-DOS used segmented architecture, a pointer had two parts (segment and offset) . Some implementations in debug mode have a pointer also contain information about the bounds of the object being pointed to. There could be others, I don't claim to have knowledge of every system that ever existed and will ever exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){
    int myVariable = 0;
    intptr_t varPointer = (intptr_t)&myVariable;

    *(int*)varPointer += 1; 
    printf("%d\n", myVariable);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. Could you explain what intptr_t is doing? Also, could you increment without the asterisk operator?

Comment: @stackoverflow909 `int` is not necessarily the size that can hold the value of the pointer. `intptr_t` is a signed integer type that is guaranteed to be a size that pointer can hold. I think that it is not possible to update the original value without dereference(`*`).

Comment: I thought int was huge. Memory addresses can be longer than int?

Comment: Could you explain the casting syntax of `*(int*)` ?

Comment: You must cast for integer values it is unclear represents a pointer which type.

Comment: No, it's the address of an integer. The second part of your comment is not a sentence and can't be parsed.

Comment: E.g `&myVariable + 1`  is called the pointer arithmetic. because it have type of  pointer rather than a mere address.

Comment: Please add all these explanations into the actual answer. This was flagged as VLQ, presumably because it's code-only, but there's clearly a lot more going on that you can easily express, since you did in the comments.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What do you mean with VLQ?

Comment: `&myVariable` is the address of an integer, and its type is `int*`. Casting to another type and back doesn't change the fact that you're using a pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: The very low quality flag. Or maybe NAA; anyway, it was in LQP when I saw this.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What do you mean NAA and LQP?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Ah, sorry. Not An Answer and Low-Quality Posts review queue.

Comment: @Jeff the address of anything is a pointer. See 6.5.3.2/3 (Semantics - Address and indirection operators)

Comment: @stackoverflow909 `*(int*)varPointer += 1;` could be changed to `varPointer += sizeof myVariable;`. However there is no avoiding the fact that you had to use the `&` operator to get this started.

Comment: There's a very long entry on this site on the non-equivalence of addresses and pointers...

Comment: @Jeff there's a very long standards document documenting the C language :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb `*(int*)varPointer += 1;` meant `myVariable += 1;`

Comment: A lot of documentation states that pointers are just addresses that contain hex numbers that correlate to other addresses. What I have gradually realized is that this it totally untrue; pointers /can/ contain addresses, but do not necessarily. To me, that means pointers should /never/ be used this way, and apparently doing so can produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, stick the revised code in an answer and I'll accept that answer, presuming it works that is.